# How to find a sequence that maximizes a ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

Given positive parameters $n$, $P$ and $Q$, what is a sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that for every $k$:
$$
\frac{1}{k}\leq a_k \leq 1
$$

which maximizes the ratio:

$$
R = \frac{P + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{Q + \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot a_k}
$$
?

*NOTE: one observation is that a maximizing sequence should be weakly decreasing (for all $k>l$, $a_k\leq a_l$). PROOF: If there exists $k>l$ with $a_k>a_l$, then switch $a_k$ with $a_l$. This strictly decreases the denominator but does not change the nominator.*

Comment: Suppose we have the optimal sequence $\{a_i\}$. Then $a_1=1$. Also, if $\frac{1}{k}\lt a_k \lt 1$ for some $k$,  then a small perturbation $\epsilon$ in $a_k$ reduces $R$. Now write $$R_m=\frac{N}{M}$$ where $R_m$  is the value for the  optimal sequence $\{a_i\}$. Then $$R_\epsilon=\frac{N+\epsilon}{M+k\epsilon}.$$ From the condition $R_m - R_\epsilon > 0$, we have $$N k \epsilon>\epsilon M$$ Since a perturbation is possible in both directions for $a_k$, the inequality is a contradiction.

Comment: @vnd so IIUYC, for every $k$, either $a_k=1$ or $a_k=1/k$?

Comment: @ Erel Segal-Halevi:  Yes. Your observation that the sequence is weakly decreasing is crucial here. For, if suppose $a_1 = a_2 = .. a_{k-1} =1$ and  $a_k = \frac{1}{k}$, then $a_t = \frac{1}{t}$ for $t>k$  is forced by the above argument.

Comment: @vnd great! So now the only thing that remains is to find the first index $k$ such that $a_k=1/k$. This looks like an easy 1-variable optimization problem. Your comment supplied the missing link. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @vnd would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the optimal sequence $\{a_i\}$. Then $a_1=1$. Also, if $\frac{1}{k}\lt a_k \lt 1$ for some $k$, then a small perturbation ϵ in $a_k$ reduces the required ratio $R$. Now write$$R_m=\frac{N}{M}$$
where $R_m$ is the value of the ratio for the optimal sequence $\{a_i\}$. Then $$R_\epsilon=\frac{N+\epsilon}{M+k\epsilon}.$$
From the condition $R_m−R_ϵ>0$, we have $$N k \epsilon>\epsilon M.$$
Since a perturbation is possible in both directions for $a_k$, the inequality is a contradiction.
Your observation that the sequence is weakly decreasing is crucial here. For, if suppose that  $a_1 = a_2 = .. a_{k-1} =1$ and $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$, then $a_t = \frac{1}{t}$ for $t>k$ is forced by the above argument.

Comment: Why does a small perturbation $\epsilon$ in $a_k$ strictly reduces the required ratio $R$ - why can't it remain the same?

Comment: You are right about this. I seem to have overlooked that the possibility exists for $Nk = M$ for some k. May be this happens for some starting values of $P, Q$ and $n$.

Comment: However if one assumes that a unique optimal sequence exists, then the arguments should stay the same. Of course, no attempt was made to prove the uniqueness of an optimal sequence.